# Owning a car in Japan and changing visa/departing for a long trip

Tags: japan, automobiles

what happens if you:

- posses a Japanese driving license
- posses a Japanese car
- posses a valid parking spot (車庫証明)
- switch from a working visa to a tourist visa and later go on a trip in Japan, thus stopping-paying/losing the valid parking spot?

Having a parking spot in Japan is needed only when buying a car? If you depart for a 2-months tour, will you still need to have/pay-for a valid parking spot?

Thanks

Comment: This might be better asked on https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/24043/owning-a-car-in-japan-and-changing-visa-departing-for-a-long-trip